# Complex Database Design: columns or data

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

For an existing database we are considering to improve part of the database design.

25 tables have very similar structures, about 90% identical columns & data types. And fairly frequent changes to the tables, for example we may need to add 2 new columns to 7 of these 25 tables. A few months later the 2 new columns may be required in 5 further tables, etc. We also get questions like how many rows in these tables have `IsActive` (see example below) = TRUE. This currently means creating 25 SQL statements and the statements are much more complex than this simple example. It just feels wrong to query 25 tables and then combine the results.

One option we discussed would be to store all data in a master table. However in total this would mean having quite a wide table and quite a lot of NULL values.

A further idea we discussed is to keep the 25 tables and create a master view, which combines these tables. The view would however need a lot of manuall maintenance and the update could get forgotten & the view would still work.

In database design one of the main concepts is: "For maximum flexibility, data is stored in columns, not in column names.", which leads us to the main question. Does anyone have experience in storing columns in a table? The columns actually contain filter criteria for business logic.

Here is an example:

**Table 1: Business Rule 1**

```
CustomerID (int) | IsPremiumCust (bool) | HasCreditCard (bool) | IsActive (bool) | OrderThreshold (int)
```

**Table 2: Business Rule 2**

```
CustomerID (int) | IsPremiumCust (bool) | HasCreditCard (bool) | IsActive (bool) | Discount (int)
```

further 23 tables like these. All with more columns than in this examples.

Suggestion: `Criteria` table

```
Criteria ID | Criteria       | Data Type    
1           | IsPremiumCust  | bool
2           | HasCreditCard  | bool
3           | IsActive       | bool
4           | OrderThreshold | int
5           | Discount       | int
```

Suggestion: Business Rule table

```
Business Rule ID | Name
     1           | Business Rule 1
     2           | Business Rule 2
```

Suggestion: Intersection table

```
CustomerID | Business Rule ID | Criteria ID | Criteria Value
------------------------------------------------------------    
      1    |      1           |       1     | TRUE
      2    |      2           |       1     | FALSE
```

I know this doesn't really work, as the Criteria Value field could have different data types. However I hope someone might have had a similar situation and can think of a full solution for this question.

This would allow us to add criteria without having to keep changing many table structures.

Comment: hit you favourite search engine with "eav database pattern" ...

Comment: It sounds like you are about to venture down the path of EAV (entity attribute value). It provides unbelievable flexibility. But when done across the entire database like this is also provides unbelievably complicated queries and data integrity is challenging. EAV has its place but what you are describing sounds like the beginning of a nightmare. Here is a great article discussing the pros and cons of EAV. https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway and here it went horribly wrong. https://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/

Comment: Thanks for your comments regarding EAV. The articles are both very interesting. I am still in discussion with the dev team whether we should try something similar to Aaron Betrand's solution.

Comment: Somewhat related question to overall design.  Can a customer fall into multiple business rules tables all at once?  do they have records in all of the tables all of the time?  Do the business rules results need to be persisted or can they be calculated on the fly?  Or why not one table with all distinct columns and another way to calculate their adherence to rules?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should have one table that has the *core fields* from your 25 common tables, with an additional field for the type of record that corresponds to the current existing table names. Then, you want one or a few supplemental tables that use the primary key for you new core table and also store just the additional fields needed by each type of record. If you find yourself with a new set of columns that only apply to a handful of existing tables, that's fine. You only need records for those records from the core table in your new supplemental table. And when those columns expand to include more of your original tables, adding records to the supplemental table is easy. You can still build a master view from this, if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I think reply to you question is good property inheritance tree for end entity. If tree will be optimized for problem domain you will be have efficient database scheme without null values. Problem with quantity of sql statements you can close by suitable ORM.